# Grand Total is incorrect is SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: dax, ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular

The number I see in the grand total is different from the sum of the rows (for previous year column [Önceki Yıl IPP]).

Table columns

[image]

Measures:

```
IPP Ciro:=SUM([Amount_])/1000
```

This measure calculates sum of revenue(Amount_)

```
Önceki Yıl IPP:=
VAR LastDaySelectionIPP =
    LASTNONBLANK ( Tarih[Tarih], [IPP Ciro] )
VAR CurrentRangeIPP =
    DATESBETWEEN ( Tarih[Tarih], MIN ( Tarih[Tarih] ), LastDaySelectionIPP )
VAR PreviousRange =
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( CurrentRangeIPP )
RETURN
    IF (
        LastDaySelectionIPP >= MIN ( Tarih[Tarih] ),
        CALCULATE ( [IPP Ciro], PreviousRange )
    )
```

This measure calculates sum of previous year revenue.

I want to compare the current year with the last year same period.

Why is the Grand total is 98.998 for previous year[Önceki Yıl IPP]?

[image]

Grand Total is incorrect is SSAS Tabular Model

Answer (score 0):

It’s not jumping out at me, but here’s how to debug it.

Add a new measure like this and add it to your table:

```
Debug:=
VAR LastDaySelectionIPP =
    LASTNONBLANK ( Tarih[Tarih], [IPP Ciro] )
VAR MinDate = MIN ( Tarih[Tarih] )
VAR CurrentRangeIPP =
    DATESBETWEEN ( Tarih[Tarih], MIN ( Tarih[Tarih] ), LastDaySelectionIPP )
VAR PreviousRange =
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( CurrentRangeIPP )
VAR WrongAnswer =
    IF (
        LastDaySelectionIPP >= MIN ( Tarih[Tarih] ),
        CALCULATE ( [IPP Ciro], PreviousRange )
    )
RETURN LastDaySelectionIPP & “,” & MinDate & “,” & [IPP Ciro] & “,” & WrongAnswer
```

It will list the values you are using in the calculation and I predict you’ll find the unexpected value. Update us on what you find!